# Error when my app triggers something from websocket

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android studio, but so far, so good!

I have an android app which is up and running together with an websocket that is running on my computer.
So when both the websocket and the app is up and running.

I could write a message, which then gets printed in the websocket terminal, and the websocket also return an message which get printed on the list on my phone. Also, if the websocket receive a special message from the app, the webscocket also return a special message which is shown on and added on the list! Perfect! Isnt it?

Now what I am trying to do is that, the app listens to a special message/event from the websocket which in this case is "SuperSpecialMessage". If the websocket sends this specific message, the application is
going to react and do something. In this case make an Invisible buttong to be visible.

**SO WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?** The problem here is that I get the error:

"android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Could someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
public class WebSocketActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Socket mSocket;
private TextView mSocketStatus;


EditText messageTextview;
ListView the_list_view_on_layout;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
String TheMessages;
List<String> list_with_messages;

Button theExtraButton;


Handler mHandler;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_websocket);


    this.mHandler = new Handler();
    m_Runnable.run();


    // Elements that are created on the layout
    mSocketStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.socketStatus);
    theExtraButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.extraBtn);
    theExtraButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    the_list_view_on_layout = findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    messageTextview = findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);


    String[] TheMessages = new String[]{};

    list_with_messages = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TheMessages));

    //ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_with_messages);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_with_messages);

    the_list_view_on_layout.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    TheSocketClass app = (TheSocketClass) getApplication();
    mSocket = app.getSocket();
    mSocket.connect();
    checkIfConnectedToSocket();



    Button sendMessageToSocketServer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendMessageToSocketBtn);
    sendMessageToSocketServer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String theTextWeWrite = messageTextview.getText().toString();

            mSocket.emit("sendTextToServer", theTextWeWrite);
            list_with_messages.add(theTextWeWrite);

            //arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });


 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSocket.on("ServerMessage", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                    list_with_messages.add(data.toString());

                    //arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // I GET ERROR HERE


                }
            });

        }

    });


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSocket.on("SuperSpecialMessage", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    theExtraButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
        }

    });


}
private void checkIfConnectedToSocket(){
    mSocket.connect();
    if (mSocket.connected() == true) {
       mSocketStatus.setText("Connected to socket!");
     mSocketStatus.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
     }
    else if (!mSocket.connected()){
        mSocketStatus.setText("Error connecting to socket!");
       mSocketStatus.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

}


}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you are initializing your array adapter with empty list ,pass your updated list to array adapter

Comment: You misunderstood something? I am talking about the button "theExtraButton" which are INVISIBLE, and I want to make it Visible after the app receives the special message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Solved!

First i made an method like this:

```
private void makeTheButtonVisible(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            theExtraButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            });
        }
```

and when the app recieve the message, the method is called like this:

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSocket.on("SuperSpecialMessage", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    makeTheButtonVisible();

                }
            });
        }

    });
```